# How do I highlight particular rows based on a custom list of dates?

Tags: microsoft-excel, highlighting

I'm building labor tracking spreadsheet that has every day of the year in it.  Some of those days are paid vacation days.  I would like to highlight the rows of those particular dates (not a range), in order to make certain the hours entered in those rows stand out (like in green, or whatever).  I have a list of holiday dates (in long date format).  I would like to use that list in order to find those dates in my main date column (also all displayed in long date), and then highlight the rest of that row.  Help would be much appreciated

Comment: If possible share some sample data especially list of holidays you are suppose to match with Date Column to Format, help us to fix the issue.

Comment: Also, please add a screenshot because it isn't clear what the worksheet looks like.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**How it works:**

- Select the list of Holidays, including header (*Dates, Check Screen Shot*).
- Press **Ctrl+Shift+F3**.
- From `Create Names From Selection`, check the `TOP ROW` & finish with **Ok**.
- Reach to `Conditional Formatting Command` and hit `New Rule`.
- Write this Formula.

`=COUNTIF(Holidays,$A2)>0`

**N.B.** In the Formula, `Holidays` is the Name Excel assigned to Holiday's Date list.

- Apply an appropriate Format & finish with `OK`.

*You find the Dates are now highlighted as matched with list of Holidays (Dates).*

*Adjust cell reference and the Holidays list as needed.*